# Drawing a convex shape with CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a right triangle with a convex hypotenuse.

1. Start with a square
2. Cut off half of it diagonally such that what is left is a right triangle.
3. Curve the hypotenuse inwards

How would I achieve this with CoreGraphics? Should I inscribe an ellipse over half of the rectangle?

Comment: A picture would say more than a thousand words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very good with math, maybe someone can elaborate on the tangent math.

Here is a custom subview drawing function to draw what your looking for. Simply make a few lines, use an arc for the hypotenuse.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 50);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 100, 50);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 100, 0);

 CGPoint tangent1 = CGPointMake(85, 25);
 CGPoint tangent2 = CGPointMake(10, 50);
 CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, tangent1.x, tangent1.y, tangent2.x, tangent2.y, 125);

 CGFloat redComponents[4] = { 1., 0., 0., 1. };
 CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, redComponents);
 CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

Comment: I notice that there is technology in XCode to create Bezier curves as well (appendBezier...), which should give greater control over the shape of the hypotenuese.

John Doner

Comment: I believe your referring to NSBezierPath, this API is not available on the iPhone.

Comment: CGContextAddCurveToPoint() does exist on the iPhone, and it would let you work with Bezier curves in this context.